# Work around for AutoFilter function VBA on Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to turn on Autofilter for the the header row on each page of my workbook before each sheet is protected with a password. I'm using Microsoft Excel for Mac, which if you're familiar with, lacks the complete functionality of VBA for Windows machines.

I saw one other question on this topic and have tried implementing that code but it hasn't worked. When I record a macro, it basically gives me the first two lines of the code below minus the 'ws.' in front.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      
   ws.Range("A1").Select
       
   Selection.AutoFilter
       
   ws.Protect "password"

   
Next ws
```

But when I add it to my larger macro, it gives me the 1004 error saying *method 'select' of object 'range' failed *

Answer (score 0):

You may need to activate the sheet first

```
Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   ws.Activate
   ws.Range("A1").Select
   Selection.AutoFilter
   ws.Protect "password"
Next ws
```

If you don't want to see worksheets flickering through the loop, switch off screen updating, then on again when the loop completes.